# How does zomato app draw free hand circle over maps in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, overlay

demo is here:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-xV6rFYT_0

I want to do the same but how do the do it?
is it overlay..if yes then how do they track inside of the circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to achieve of you put a `View` over the map and manage the `MotionEvent`s:

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/draggable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private View draggableView;
    private List<LatLng> polylinePoints = new ArrayList<>();
    private Polyline polyline;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);

        draggableView = findViewById(R.id.draggable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        draggableView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                LatLng position = mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(
                        new Point((int) motionEvent.getX(), (int) motionEvent.getY()));

                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (polyline != null) {
                        polyline.remove();
                        polyline = null;

                        polylinePoints.clear();
                    }
                    polylinePoints.add(position);
                    polyline = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(polylinePoints));
                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    polylinePoints.add(position);
                    polyline.setPoints(polylinePoints);
                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    // Close the polyline?
                    // Send the polyline to make a search?
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot..it works great..just one thing how do I analyse whats inside the selected area like zomato does 
I want to find schools in selected area by user

Comment: There are too many different good answers to that question. I think you should ask another question explaining your background and needs so others can give rich answers.